# how to get matplotlib pop up window when plotting the python chart in RStudio?

Tags: python, r, matplotlib

I'm trying to use Rstudio for python programming and I want to plot some charts in python but when do that chart is getting shown in the default Rstudio plot window (down right corner) I want to get that same plot to displayed in matplotlib pop up window [this is the screenshot of Rstudio](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qcq89.png) plot window and I want the plot to be displayed in [this window like pop up](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jhaed.png)
many thanks for considering my request.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I don't use `Rstudio` but maybe you shouldn't use `matplotlib.use('Agg')` because normally it defines what engine it use to display plots.